Calculate sum of data-attribute value based on the values in all input fields
I'm trying to find the sum of input values within multiple inputs.
My input form is something like below. Here I want to get input's data-attribute value for this calculation.


$(document).ready(function() {
  const $total = $('#total');

  $('.number').blur(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.number').each(function() {
      const data = $(this).data('value');
      if (data != "") {
        sum += parseFloat(data);
      }
    });

    $total.val(sum);

  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="0.10">
  <input type="text" name="b" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="0.20">
  <input type="text" name="c" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="0.40">
  <input type="text" name="d" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="1.00">

  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00 m³" readonly="true">
</form>



Eg:
if name="a" is 1 then name="total" value should be 0.10 m³
if name="a" is 2 then name="total" value should be 0.20 m³
Let say I have input values something like this;
a = 2
b = 1
c = 3
d = 1 

Then total should be;
0.10 + 0.10 + 0.20 + 0.40 + 0.40 + 0.40 + 1.00 = 2.60 m³

But it doesn't work for me. That mean when changing a input I am getting a total of all data-attribute values.

You forgot to multiple by the input's value:  * $(this).val()

@fdomn-m, As my above input form, you can see there are four inputs with data-attribute values. So doesn't work mean, when I trying to change 1 input I can get the total of all four  data-attribute values at once.

yes I realised, so deleted that comment.  Apologies to waste your time.   "total of data-attributes" is the relevant part - not "total of data-attributes multiplied by their input value" which is what you want.

@fdomn-m, Yes, when the relevant input changes, the relevant data-attribute value should be used for the final calculation.



$(document).ready(function() {
  const $total = $('#total');

  // Calculate total whenever an input loses focus
  $('.number').on('blur', function() {
    let sum = 0;

    $('.number').each(function() {
      const inputVal = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
      const dataValue = parseFloat($(this).data('value')) || 0;

      sum += inputVal * dataValue;
    });
    $total.val(sum.toFixed(2) + ' m³');
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="0.10">
  <input type="text" name="b" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="0.20">
  <input type="text" name="c" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="0.40">
  <input type="text" name="d" value="0" class="number" maxlength="2" data-value="1.00">

  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00 m³" readonly="true">
</form>



inputs value is parsed as an int.
if the input is empty makes to 0.
inputs data-value attribute is parsed as a float.
using for each to input field multiply the value entered by the data-value attribute and add it to the running total

Is not the most jquery code but here is my solution:

You have to reference the current element in the foreach loop as far as I know, as the function's second argument.

The .data('...') or .attr(...) methods didn't work as I expected, maybe I'm missing something, so I used the native getAttribute('...').

toFixed(2) shows only 2 decimal places.


$(document).ready(function() {
   const $total = $('#total');
  
   $('.number').blur(function() {
       let sum = 0;

       $('.number').each(function(ind,elem) {
           let dataValue = elem.getAttribute('data-value');
           let value = elem.value;
           sum += dataValue * value;
       });
    
       sum = sum.toFixed(2);
       $total.val(`${sum} m³`); // string interpolation
    
    });
});

Hope it worked!
